# Columns not loading in Data Source Explorer or JPA Generate Custom Entities Wizard in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, teradata

I am trying to generate a JPA Entity class based on a table in a Teradata database using the JPA Tools in Eclipse. My Eclipse version is Luna 4.4.1. I've established a connection to the database via JDBC and I'm able to load my schema in the Data Source Explorer. I've also successfully executed queries from the SQL Scrapbook.

The Data Source Explorer sees my schema, and all of the tables in the schema, however when I click the drop down for the Columns, nothing appears.

The closest question I've seen so far is this: [EclipseLink and JPA columns of table not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246846/eclipselink-and-jpa-columns-of-table-not-showing-up/23334207#23334207)

However, my issue is that no columns appear when I expand the nodes of the tree.

When I attempt to create my Entity class using the Generate Custom Entity Wizard, I can select the schema and select tables from the schema, but none of the columns load.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who comes this way looking for an answer, I did figure it out.

The User that you use for your database connection in Eclipse needs to have SELECT  privileges on DBC.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. However, I was unable to resolve it. Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by "Select privileges on DBC'? I am trying to connect with the root user, which must have permissions to everything...

Comment: I was having the Select Privileges but the columns were still not visible. Changing the mysql connector helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same using with MY Sql driver "mysql-connector-java-6.0.6-bin.jar" . I just changed the driver version to "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar" and it started working .

Answer (score 0):

Does the table you're trying to expand have a primary key? I've had issues with generating entities when there is no primary key defined on the table. The workaround was to add one then remove it after generation if it's unwanted.

Comment: It has a Primary Index. I've tried recreating the table with a PK instead and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turned out that my Database Connection was set to User access only. I changed it to All and I was then able to generate the columns.

You can do this by going to Data Source Explorer -> Database Connections -> Right click and select Properties under your connection -> Change Catalog drop down to "All".